# Sync values from modal within Formik in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I working on user registration form using formik in react js. user structure will look like below

```
user : {
          name:'',
          email:'',
          apps:[{
            name:'',
            role:'',
            permissions: [{
              service:'*',
              access:'R'
            }]
          }]
        }
```

user can have access to multiple applications and each application can have a list of permissions. Above user having access to one app which have single permission. I am trying to show permissions in a modal, in modal we have to list services and their access, this access will be represented in a drop-down and can be modified, so if access is modified we have to sync this updated access with original user permission. initially modal body will look like below

| service | access |
| --- | --- |
| * | R |

Now we have modified access to W like below

| service | access |
| --- | --- |
| * | W |

so when we submit original user form then access should be updated and finally user should look like below

```
user : {
          name:'enterd_name',
          email:'enterd_email',
          apps:[{
            name:'selected_appname',
            role:'selected_role',
            permissions: [{
              service:'*',
              access:'W'
            }]
          }]
        }
```

I tried Codesandbox example here ... https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-within-formik-0hpqb but no success. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I didn't understand your question properly, but from what I'm gathering you want to update the state with the PermissionModal values,

If it's that you can always use the `setFieldValue` prop it's accessed same way as onSubmit to change the formik State.

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void

so say you if you want the state to be updated on modal closure, you can maybe you can call `setFieldValue` with new state.

like in your example if you want to update name you can do something like
`setFieldValue("user.name", "world");`